# WordNet Export CSV Java program gives error

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, wordnet, jwi

I cloned WordNetToCSV program codes from github but it gives this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class GeneralWordNetExport

The github repository link is: https://github.com/eureko/WordNetToCSVFiles/

I also installed WordNet 2.1 for Windows download link for wordnet 2.1 setup is: http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/2.1/WordNet-2.1.exe

could you help me?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with the Eclipse Oxygen.1a Java IDE. Delete the run configuration (in _Run > Run Configurations..._) and try again (right-click `GeneralWordNetExport.java` and choose _Run As > Java Application_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating apache-jena-libs maven dependency from 3.0 release to 3.5.0 release, now it works faultless.